# Limit of argument size of a command (for ex: in grep "$some_argument_size" filename)

Tags: grep, arguments, limit, long-integer, xargs

I'm running a shell script and line# 15 is:

```
grep "$var1$var2" somefilewithonly10000lines_letsay
```

and getting an error:

```
line 15: /bin/grep: Argument list too long
```

What's the limit for the grep command's pattern? -- which when I reach, gives me the above error message.

Comment: Post sample data and what your like to get out of it.  You can have lots of stuff inside `var1` and `var2` that may make this fail.

Comment: If you use Linux: Your complete commandline is longer than the value you get from: `getconf ARG_MAX`

Comment: @Jotne, I agree. value for $var1$var2 is very big. That's my question, what's the limit for that pattern size. For ex: $var1$var2 are like: "\([A-Z][A-Z][0-9][a-z][a-z].....many times may be more than 500 such patterns...somemorepatterns". Now, the ? is not, why don't I squeeze my pattern to "\([A-Za-z0-9]{2,}" or something, but ... what's the limit for that pattern size that grep can handle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Cyrus ARG_MAX on my machine is 131072. Do you mean this is the limit? http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/ shows the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THe following will tell the limit. Thanks Cyrus.

```
$ getconf ARG_MAX
```

More info: http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/